# Какие советы можете дать по улучшению данного кода?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Добрый день есть такой код фильтра на JS
Буду рад если потратите минуту своего времени и критичным взглядом напишите что следует поменять и что улучшить
заранее спасибо

```
$('#filter-aply').on('click',function(){


    var etage = $('.filter-item__buttons').children('.button.active').data('etg')
    etage = parseFloat(etage)


    // Square
    var squareMin = $("#js-range__metr").data('from')
    squareMin = parseFloat(squareMin)

    var squareMax = $("#js-range__metr").data('to')
    squareMax = parseFloat(squareMax)


    // Price
    var priceMin = $("#js-range__price").data('from')
    priceMin = parseFloat(priceMin)

    var priceMax = $("#js-range__price").data('to')
    priceMax = parseFloat(priceMax)

    var dataCount = 0;

    var saleItems = $('.sale-item')



    for(var i = 0; i<saleItems.length; i++){

      var item = saleItems[i]

      var etageLocal = $(item).data('etage')
      etageLocal = parseFloat(etageLocal)

      var price = $(item).data('price')
      price = parseFloat(price)

      var square = $(item).data('square')
      square = parseFloat(square)


      if(price <= priceMax && price >= priceMin){
        eqPrice = true;
      }
      else{
        eqPrice = false;
      }
      if(etageLocal == etage){
        eqEtage = true;
      }
      else{
        eqEtage = false;
      }
      if(square <= squareMax && square >= squareMin){
        eqSquare = true
      }
      else{
        eqSquare = false;
      }


      if(eqEtage == false || eqPrice == false || eqSquare == false){
        $(item).removeClass('showed')
        $(item).removeAttr('data-count')
      }
      if(eqPrice == true && eqEtage == true && eqSquare == true){
        $(item).addClass('showed')
        dataCount++;
        $(item).attr('data-count', dataCount)
        $('.sale-item__eye').attr('data-position', dataCount)
        $('.sale-item[data-count="1"]').click()
      }



    }


  })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выражения такого вида:

```
if (<выражение>) {
    <переменная> = true;
} else {
    <переменная> = false;
}
```

всегда можно упростить до:

```
<переменная> = <выражение>;
```

Тогда вместо:

```
if(price <= priceMax && price >= priceMin){
    eqPrice = true;
}
else{
    eqPrice = false;
}
if(etageLocal == etage){
    eqEtage = true;
}
else{
    eqEtage = false;
}
if(square <= squareMax && square >= squareMin){
    eqSquare = true
}
else{
    eqSquare = false;
}
```

Будет:

```
eqPrice = price <= priceMax && price >= priceMin;
eqEtage = etageLocal == etage;
eqSquare = square <= squareMax && square >= squareMin;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

посмотри [код](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?noImplicitAny=false&target=99&ssl=23&ssc=13&pln=23&pc=17#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAEjgMyhEcDkArAjgVwFMoBPTAKHIGMIA7AZ3mFoCUBDWgc0LgF44AFAA8AXHFr4QAI2IAaOCGZiJ0uQrajxkmVACUfAHyDFtOAB5%20QuADJrcKxfVD9AfjgwoROGORsANvSE1HSMcMD0AKIE-nyCbPJS%20rxGbHz8UsEM8P5%20ACqePPwCbFBQYlIQEH6EHADaALpJKaUAdIQAbsQkAriGcL28-B5EuuQA9GNwNFlwOfleRSVlcBVVNbQNTYjFpbptbFQAFgICwLK4WwNDBaPkCAKYAMTIwH4wxAC0bGB%20ZHt0DyofmAVAA1ph5IUjABvchweFTELwQgwNjcZTaYixMAlQIAMT8EDYMAE90wLReb0%20wHeIAA%20nSpPgYDAQpg9kdXgATKCEWgPFpMll0FoHGDATrslpc4lsB4ozjs0YIxEzKAYfj3ABEj2w9A%20UA43AZIBRUC1yoR01CUDAsW1uv1hq4hAZYCgIMIFrhVqRcHo0V5YlqKh08lDxHqsVqPpV8JxUHxhOJAnV0tlD1Q6CVsljcYTSaJJLTMtRD1ZSrz9Tz1vg7s9wYjUHDmKgUf4MbjCILhAJRdTYHTZcwWZAObzKp7fZTtqHcswFd0lvh1ZV1XgpbYAGEIPhaDAMaooLEAAwAbjzEzgH1kHzzZJa9H8hA%20NMIY72IG%20JzOcEIfi2WEu3hdcwlpe0BH-Zc4yvG872A1VQhRNFCAARUPHRsVxXtkxJN8QDneVUW4SsENrOB6yoNCMKxfgp1w05aUIzBKMIUjgPIgN8BKaitCPLDExw-t8OYriePYrtYNvCdfRmQgBjgTsEIRZh2BdARWNQ%20QWh01jdFzZSVMiaI-Eg4i0Mhcz9JkrtVKNQgBDE3ktLgHTH0DQhrIQ1dgKk%20DgOAZA4j8PICkgi59CAwywPfUUuS5Lc-DYeh6AeehDggAB3QguXZGy403Hc9xgABqEqL2imKCOJDwHk3D4aGKiE4EK3d92ghCHyfapX1pBlCBINi9hqqA6tlD5IHoGlgDoZrWuKjrgK659evfWp6sa-deC1ABGLV6ilIEQVBARFvhABfP8Ah4KLDJE3kQAgTpEuS1LMHSrKcryyr7vfJ7CAAQRZUbMA2tqYG%204Dzrzc7RlhoA)

### из основного

```
// один раз нашли
const els = $('.className');

// много раз использовали
els.addClass('red');
els.addClass('green').addClass('gray')
```

---

рекомендую к ознакомлению [api.jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com)